# Create new git branch from remote branch on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I've been discussing with my team and searching the internet, but I cannot figure out how to create a new git branch locally based on a remote branch hosted on GitHub. It seems like there should be a way to do this.

I've tried the following, but when I push, it pushes to the incorrect (origin/release/1.0) branch instead of pushing to a new branch (feature/123) on GitHub.

```
git checkout -b feature/123 origin/release/1.0
```

Currently, the workflow that works is:

```
git checkout release/1.0
git pull
git checkout -b feature/123
```

I have to do that quite a bit though and it feels like I should be able to skip having to pull in the release/1.0 branch locally, and instead, create my branch with one command.

Is there a way to do this, or do we have to just keep pulling in the latest release and then branching from there locally?

### Solution

Update global git config

```
git config --global branch.autoSetupMerge false
```

Create new branch from latest release

```
$ git fetch --all
$ git checkout -b feature/123 origin/release/1.0
$ git push --set-upstream origin feature/123
```

Comment: When you make the branch, is there a message like `Branch 'feature/123' set up to track remote branch 'release/1.0' from 'origin'.`?

Comment: `$ git checkout -b test/123 origin/release/2021.1`
Switched to a new branch 'test/123'
Branch 'test/123' set up to track remote branch 'release/2021.1' from 'origin'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you branch from a remote branch, Git automatically sets up the remote as the "tracking branch". This is the remote branch it will use when pushing and pulling.

```
$ git checkout -b feature/123 origin/release/1.0
Branch 'feature/123' set up to track remote branch 'release/1.0' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'feature/123'
```

You don't want it to track the remote. You can turn it off with `--no-track`.

```
$ git checkout --no-track -b feature/123 origin/release/1.0
```

And you can change the behavior globally with [`branch.autoSetupMerge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchautoSetupMerge).

```
$ git config --global branch.autoSetupMerge false
```

Now feature/123 has no tracking branch. When you run `git push` it has to guess where to push your branch to. This can be configured with `push.default`. You probably want `simple` which is the default.

> simple - pushes the current branch with the same name on the remote.

---

> I have to do that quite a bit though and it feels like I should be able to skip having to pull in the release/1.0 branch locally, and instead, create my branch with one command.

Note that you still have to `git fetch` the remote to ensure you have the latest version.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b feature/123 origin/release/1.0
```

This is the decentralized nature of Git, it does not assume you have a connection to your remotes. Though it's safe to just `git fetch` periodically.

And to ensure your feature branch remains up to date with the latest changes, you will have to periodically update your branch from release/1.0.

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/release/1.0
```

This is the nature of working with others.